# detect objects of any shape from image and color individual object

Tags: iphone, ios, opencv

I am new to opencv and doing some like detect different objects from image and apply effects on individual object. I find edges, and using following code to get contours, but how how to proceed ahead i dont know. Any help ????
Thanks in advance

```
cv::Mat edges;
cv::Canny(gray, edges, 50, 150);

std::vector< std::vector<cv::Point> > c;
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
cv::findContours(edges, c, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(edges.rows, edges.cols, CV_8UC1);
  for (size_t i=0; i<c.size(); i++)
   {
   for (size_t j = 0; j < c[i].size(); j++)
   {
    cv::Point p = c[i][j];
    points.push_back(p);
    // printf(" %d \t",p.x);
   }


}
cv::Mat crop(inputFrame.rows, inputFrame.cols, CV_8UC3);
inputFrame.copyTo(outputFrame, mask);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have chosen to identify the objects through their contour, I suggest that you continue with the "Generalized Hough Transform" ([PDF](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~dana/HoughT.pdf)). You will have to create reference contours for the objects, that you want to recognize (from every conceivable viewpoint).

Another option, that might be interesting to you is to look into [segmentation algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_segmentation) in order to select certain objects in the image. Without knowing anything about the objects, that you are looking for and the images that you are processing, it is impossible to give good recommendations. There is no general purpose algorithm that works on every image (at least as far as I know).

To give you an idea about the state-of-the-art object class recognition, you can have a look at the [PASCAL VOC Challenge](http://pascallin.ecs.soton.ac.uk/challenges/VOC/). If your problem is simpler than the challenge (e.g. a small set of immutable objects, that stand in front of a one colored background), you should specify it in your question, and maybe someone can give you better suggestions.